# Can I write the passive of this sentence by using "got"?

Tags: passive-voice

> Context: *This drug has affected me a lot.*
>
> Passive: *I **have got** affected by this drug a lot.*

I have not used "have been", so is it correct?

Comment: _I have got affected_ is not grammatical English.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I think it's because the "got" passive is only available in simple tenses, not in perfect tenses. So _I got affected by this drug_ is fine, but not _I have got affected by this drug_.

Comment: @ColinFine Your punt is far more elegant than mine. In idiomatic (USAian, primarily) English, I suppose we can say that _to get VERBed_ is a form of the passive. Isn't the OP's sentence then just the past form of the passive?

Comment: Yes, @P.E.Dant, _to get VERBed_ is indeed a form of the passive, but it isn't used in perfect tenses. I just searched on GloWbE: there are only 833 instances of "HAVE got VERBed", and most of these are not passives but other idioms like "get married" and "get rid of". In contrast there are 162 468 instances of "GET VERBed". (Many of those are "get rid of" etc, but the much greater frequencies are striking)

Comment: @ColinFine  It's not *great* English but something like "I had got sick" seems idiomatic, at least for some speakers.

Comment: @ColinFine In the vernacular, we seem to see this construction with the reflexive: _"He has [got/gotten] himself killed."_ _"We have [got/gotten] ourselves in a fix."_ This seems to me both passive and perfect. Where is my thinking amiss?

Comment: @Andrew: "get sick" is not passive in either form or meaning.

Comment: @ColinFine  OK, "had got damaged" then.  I wouldn't normally use it, but I can imagine it being used.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: Good point about "got himself killed". But I don't think it is the same construction. It is a sort of passive in meaning, but it is nevertheless agentive (indeed, it is formally a causitive, just like "I'll get him registered"). I agree that in the case of "get oneself killed", it doesn't sound much like agency; but I think that when we use it we are nevertheless implying that the subject contributed to the result.

Comment: @ColinFine Spot on as regards agency; that's where I came a cropper here.

Comment: @Andrew: yes, "It had got damaged" does seem to work. I'm not so sure about "it's got damaged", though. Need more thought.

Answer (score 2):

If you use that construction, "**got**" must be "**gotten**" ([at least in American and Canadian English](http://grammarist.com/usage/got-gotten/)).

It's true that this is a kind of second passive voice and is used now and then.

> He was killed in the last airstrike.
>   
> He got killed in the last airstrike.
>
> He had been enlisted.
>   
> He had gotten enlisted.
>
> He was sent a letter.
>   
> He got sent a letter.

But two things stand out that you should take notice of:

1. If it works at all in the sentence, it's less formal, possibly even childishly familiar. For example, imagine an officer informing a new widow of her husband's death in battle.

> **✓** Ma'am, your husband has **been killed** by enemy forces.
>   
> **✗** Ma'am, your husband has **gotten killed** by enemy forces.
>   
> *(This second one sounds somewhat childlike and is not well suited to the scenario.)*

2. I have an inkling that one only uses "to get ___ed" for verbs of limited aspect; that is, verbs that describe one-time actions.

> **✓** She has always run into fans at her concerts and has **gotten photographed** at every one.
>   
> **✗** She always plays a few fan favourites, and her performances have always **gotten adored**.
>   
> *(This should be "been adored".)*

Because of this second caveat in particular, I recommend "have been" here.

If you want to be safe, you can always use "to be ___ed"; it has neither of these issues.

P.S. "a lot" in this sentence means "many times". Consider "heavily affected" or "strongly affected" if you don't mean it happened more than once.

Comment: "Had gotten affected" is ...  well, I guess it's *possible* but it sounds like a vernacular, similar to "done did", "That medicine done did affect me something powerful!"  I don't know if it would ever sound *natural* coming from someone who doesn't speak that vernacular.

Comment: @Andrew: calling it "a vernacular" to me obscures the fact that you are talking about a _dialect_ (or several dialects).

Comment: "Gotten" is rare in Britsh Englis, in any sense.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that "get + PP" is an alternative passive in spoken English; but it is rarely used in a perfect tense. So

> I got affected by this drug a lot.

is fine; but for the present perfect, you need a different form, such as

> I have been affected by this drug a lot

I have not seen this restriction documented, but I just searched in GloWbE (the corpus of Global Web-based English), and I find 833 instances of "HAVE got VERBed" (543 instances if I remove instances of "have got rid of" and "have got married", which do not function as passives), as against 162468 instances of "GET VERBed" (116430 if I remove "got rid of" and "got married"). 
In other words, in that corpus, only about 0.5% of "got" passives are in perfect tenses.

Comment: Hmm.. this analysis is incomplete. (1) What about "HAVE gotten VERBed"? (2) How can we know the significance of 0.5% unless we know the proportion of perfect tenses in general? Or at least, for the sake of side-by-side comparison, the ratio of "HAVE been VERBed" to "be VERBed"? Percentages don't say much without context.

Comment: Fair comment. The numbers are 223340 for "HAVE been VERBed" against 2067790 for "BE VERBed" - that's something over 10%.

Comment: Thanks. And if we add "HAVE gotten VERBed" minus a (quick, not careful) removal of "married" and "rid", we can add about 1,100 verbs to the now-joint "HAVE got/gotten VERBed", but it's still fairly insignificant.